# CSS translate3d causes blurred text, no scalings

Tags: css, transform

Applying `translate3d()` causes blur.
I'm not using any scales.
Please crispize it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VS6rG/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding background-color may helpful and also do the following

```
 -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

use `font-size: 200%;`

it will be apt for you... Hope it helps

Comment: it only seems like sharp but it's still blurred, increasing font-size is not a solution

Comment: What you are actually doing is, you are translating it in Z-axis. which is nothing but zooming or scaling.. So it will blur. So Only Way is to do this.